# How to make WASD equivalent input on mobile in Unity?

Tags: unity, android

I'm familiar with Unity 3d, but I haven't made phone games before.

I have already looked into the input manager to no evail. The problem is that I don't know how to make a WASD-like input on a phone with a touch screen.

How could I do it?

Comment: A pretty common method is to have a virtual joystick in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link to study up on joysticks in unity:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Joystick

Comment: While this may be helpful, link based answers are not considered complete, as they are rendered useless if the link goes down. Instead, you could summarise the important points in your answer, and provide the link for extended reading.